# No cargo signos si un campo está vacío en SharedPreferences (Hacer código más corto)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Me explico, ya que no sabía que título poner.

Estoy realizando lo siguiente, guardo los textos que escribo en tres `EditText` en `SharedPreferences` y luego los recibo en otra clase, para terminar cargándolos en `mnsj`.

El código funciona perfectamente, pero a medida que añada más personas creo que el código va a quedar demasiado largo... Seguramente haya alguna manera de acortarlo. ¿Alguna idea?

`Activity`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mnsj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mnsj);

        compra1 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
        compra2 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
        compra3 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // cargo los datos de SharedPreferences y además añado €\n

        compra1.setText(prefs.getString("Persona1", "") + "€\n");
        compra2.setText(prefs.getString("Persona2", "") + "€\n");
        compra3.setText(prefs.getString("Persona3", "") + "€\n");

        //compruebo si solamente envia €\n sin los datos de la Persona 
        if (compra1 != null && compra1.getText().equals("€\n")) {
         // si es así, lo elimino para que no muestre nada
            compra1.setText("");
        }
        if (compra2 != null && compra2.getText().equals("€\n")) {
            compra2.setText("");
        }
        if (compra3 != null && compra3.getText().equals("€\n")) {
            compra3.setText("");
        }

        // recibo los datos

        mnsj.setText("DATOS" + "\n" + "\n" + "Nombre:" + "\n" + compra1.getText() + compra2.getText() +  compra3.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Si usas preferencias hace tiempo realizaste una pregunta donde estaba agregando un valor default. este valor default se puede asignar si no tiene valor la preferencia.

Comment: @Jorgesys no serviria ya que quedarian `-` si los 3 valores no existieran, aunque dudo tambien de mi respuesta si es lo mas eficiente...

Comment: mmm y que desea UserNameYo si los 3 valores no tienen datos? que n aparezca nada? es decir en lugar de -- que no aparezca nada?

Comment: claro, no deberian aparecer... creo yo :S

Comment: No permitiré que se pueda avanzar sin rellenar al menos un `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar `TextUtils`

```
String datos = "";
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
if (!prefs.getString("Persona1", "").isEmpty()) {
    list.add(prefs.getString("Persona1", ""));
}
if (!prefs.getString("Persona2", "").isEmpty()) {
    list.add(prefs.getString("Persona3", ""));
}
if (!prefs.getString("Persona3", "").isEmpty()) {
    list.add(prefs.getString("Persona3", ""));
}
mnsj.setText("DATOS" + TextUtils.join("-", list));
```

Comment: Edite la pregunta! :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `replaceAll`, reemplazando dos o más "-" por un único guión.

```
String s = "Persona Uno -- Persona tres - Persona cuatro --- Persona siete ---- Persona once";
System.out.println (s.replaceAll ("[--]+", "-"));

"Persona Uno - Persona tres - Persona cuatro - Persona siete - Persona once"
```

Tener en cuenta que esta solución si bien implica **menos código es menos performante**, ya que implica reprocesar el string generado, reemplazando caracteres inncesarios que podrían no haber sido ingresados directamente.

Comment: me voto por tener menos codigo y astucia

Answer (score 1):

En esto casos el operador ternario puede ser muy útil, puedes sustituir los  `+ "-" +`  de la primera opción que ponías por:

```
+ ("".equals(prefs.getString("Persona2", ""))?"":"-") +
```

De ésta forma si "Persona2" está relleno te pondrá el guión.

Answer (score 0):

Una validación más corta sería :

```
persona1.setText(prefs.getString("Persona1","").equals("")?"":prefs.getString("Persona1","")+"-");
persona2.setText(prefs.getString("Persona2","").equals("")?"":prefs.getString("Persona2","")+"-");
persona3.setText(prefs.getString("Persona3","").equals("")?"":prefs.getString("Persona3",""));
```

Comment: Edite la pregunta! :)